# C++ Dynamic object construction

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base class,

```
class Msg
{
   public:

     ParseMsg()
     {
         ParseMsgData();
         ParseTrailer();
     }
     virtual void ParseMsgData() = 0;
     ParseTrailer();

};
```

and derived classes,

```
class InitiateMsg : public Msg
{
    public:
    void ParseMsgData() { ... }
};


class ReadOperationMsg  public Msg
{
   public:
    void ParseMsgData() { ... }
};


class WriteOperationMsg  public Msg
{ 
   public:

    void ParseMsgData() { ... }
};
```

and the scenario is below,

```
    void UsageFunction(string data)
    {
      Msg* msg = ParseHeader(data);
      ParseMsg
    }

   Msg* ParseHeader(string data)
   {

        Msg *msg = NULL;
           ....
         switch() 
         {

            case 1: 

                 msg = new InitiateMsg();
                 break;
            case 2:
                 msg = new ReadOperationMsg{();
                 break;
             case 3:
                 msg = new WriteOperationMsg{();
                 break;
               ....

         }

          return msg;           
    }
```

based on the data ParseHeader method will decide which object has to be created, So I have implemented ParseHeader function outside the class where I am using. How can I make the ParseHeader function inside the Msg class and then use it?

In C# the same is achieved by defining ParseHeader  method as static with in class and use it from outside,

Comment: You're calling an virtual method from within the base class constructor.  I *highly* doubt this will do what you want it to.

Comment: @AndréCaron: In fact, as the function is _pure_ virtual, the call will cause _undefined behavior_.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: I know, but even if it was just a virtual function (in which case it wouldn't be undefined behavior), it still wouldn't do what OP wants.

Comment: derived classes are missing their parent(s)... (I suppose just a hurry-typo, like others in the switch)

Comment: None of your "derived" classes inherit from `Msg`, and all your methods are private.

Comment: Sorry for typo and I missed to derive Msg in derived classes I will edit it now. once again sorry for the inconvinient.

Answer (score 4):

You are in need of **[Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern#C.2B.2B)** Design pattern. It is custom made for a scenario like yours.
The inline link explains in much more in detail with an simple example than I could here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, before anything useful comments, you forget to declare them as public and forget to declare the inherit relation in your class definitions.

To your question, why not directly declare the ParseHeader function as a public member method of the base class Msg. I cannot see any problems if you doing so.

There may be some dependence problem. You need to put the method as a declaration in Msg and define the body in a cpp file. Something like:

```
// in Msg.h
// all other lines are omitted
public:
  Msg* ParseHeader(string data);


// in Msg.cpp
#include "Msg.h"
#include "InitiateMsg.h"
#include "ReadOperationMsg.h"
#include "WriteOperationMsg.h"

Msg* Msg::ParseHeader(string data) {
// .....
}
```

also, if you want to differentiate exactly which class it is when you have a base pointer.
If I am doing it, I will declare a emun in the base class to remember it. Something like:

```
// Msg.h
class Msg{
public:
    enum type_t {
      TBase,
      TInit,
      TRead,
      TWrite
    } type;
```

Then in each different construction method, define a different type_t to the type variable. As a result you can always tell which class the pointer is pointer to and do dynamic class casting without miss trials.

Comment: Thanks for looking into my question. I can have ParseHeader as pulic method in Msg. But this parseHeader will decide which (Derived) Msg I need to create? In this case how to handle it?

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian I dont get your question quite well. Personally I believe your switch would work. Even the pointer is a base pointer, the method called using the base pointer will be the overridden virtual method in the derived class. Actually I am using this technique in my project and it works well. Unless I can see some error messages, I disagree with Andre and Charles.